# JavassistProxyFactory failing with java.lang.ClassCastException: mypkg.myObjE_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

Tags: hibernate, proxy

I'm using hibernate 5.0.2 with weblogic 12. I have a standalone app that initializes the context and then calls a EJB in weblogic. I'm getting below error message when i run my standalone app.

> Oct 20, 2015 8:56:52 PM org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory deserializeProxy
>   ERROR: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.fedex.net2.persistence.pojo.ParameterDefinitionE
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fedex.net2.persistence.pojo.ParameterDefinitionE_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.deserializeProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:156)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy.readResolve(SerializableProxy.java:116)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1810)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>           at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:208)
>           at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:602)
>           at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:204)
>           at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
>           at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:264)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:477)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:285)
>           at com.fedex.net2.parameter.ParameterSBean_cswnpo_EOImpl_12130_WLStub.findAllParameterValuesListForSeqNo(Unknown Source)
>           at com.fedex.net2.parameter.Parameter.getParamValue(Parameter.java:122)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.ChannelDef.getChnlParams(ChannelDef.java:310)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.CommInDaemon.connectChannel(CommInDaemon.java:696)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.CommInDaemon.main(CommInDaemon.java:278)

Followed by below exception.

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.fedex.net2.persistence.pojo.ParameterDefinitionE
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.deserializeProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:163)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy.readResolve(SerializableProxy.java:116)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1810)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>           at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:208)
>           at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:602)
>           at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:204)
>           at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
>           at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:264)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:477)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:285)
>           at com.fedex.net2.parameter.ParameterSBean_cswnpo_EOImpl_12130_WLStub.findAllParameterValuesListForSeqNo(Unknown Source)
>           at com.fedex.net2.parameter.Parameter.getParamValue(Parameter.java:122)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.ChannelDef.getChnlParams(ChannelDef.java:310)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.CommInDaemon.connectChannel(CommInDaemon.java:696)
>           at com.fedex.net2.comm.daemon.CommInDaemon.main(CommInDaemon.java:278)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fedex.net2.persistence.pojo.ParameterDefinitionE_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.deserializeProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:156)
>           ... 35 more

What i'm not understanding is why my standalone app is failing to access data. Is it related to Lazy loading. Am i doing something wrong.

I have correct jars in the class path. Verified 100 times so far. Still not able to figure out why?

Any thoughts???

Comment: downgrading to HIbernate 3.6.4 helped with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

downgrading to Hibernate 3.6.4 helped with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

add to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module("javassist:javassist") {
            replacedBy("org.javassist:javassist")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the lay man question. Not yet familiar with gradle, But exactly are the lines above mean. Can you please explain.