# Hibernate 5 Javassist ClassCastException: cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, javassist, hibernate-5.x

I am getting below error when I use lazy loading in hibernate annotation:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

I am using `Hibernate 5.0.11.Release` using `Spring Boot 1.4.7.Release`.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:296)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:362)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:443)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:436)
at com.hmc.nurseline.data.hibernate.NLDaoImpl.findNurselineCall(NLDaoImpl.java:85)
at com.hmc.nurseline.data.NLDaoTest.testFindNurselineCall(NLDaoTest.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:130)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:671)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4536)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:359)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:450)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:359)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:123)
... 65 more
```

Please let me know if you are able to detect issue from above error trace

Can you anyone explain how hibernate works when we use lazy loading and what is the concept of proxy using `javassist.util.proxy`?

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:362)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:436)
    at com.hmc.nurseline.data.hibernate.NLDaoImpl.findNurselineCall(NLDaoImpl.java:85)
    at com.hmc.nurseline.data.NLDaoTest.testFindNurselineCall(NLDaoTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4536)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:450)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:359)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hmc.nurseline.model.customer.NurselineCustomerModel_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:123)
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: Please show the output of **mvn dependency:tree**. Please edit it into the question, do not try to post it in a comment as that will be unreadable.

Comment: @Gimby, thank you for time, it was due to dependency conflict. Earlier I added exclusions but scope was in provided and exclusion did not work. Once I remove scope, exclusion worked.

Comment: That's strange, scope should not influence exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have similar problem which came from the existence of conflicting libraries.

Try to find the dependencies in you `pom.xml` which have the `org.javassist` in their dependency tree and exclude that explicitly from each of them. The most common ones to look at would be `hibernate-core`, `hibernate-entitymanager` and `spring-data-jpa`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${my.hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then simply add that dependency manually so that there is only one source of that library in the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have to add
 '<exclusion>
 <groupId>jboss</groupId>
 <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
</exclusion>' 
This resolved my issue

Comment: For me i had to remove dependency from jboss as well as from project pom with hibernate dependency

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle users,

Execute the following command for listing all the dependencies that have javassist included

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency javassist
```

and in my case, there were two modules of javassist, where there should have been one of these, and this seems to create the issue.

1. javassist:javassist
2. org.javassist:javassist

Andrey's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250332/javassistproxyfactory-failing-with-java-lang-classcastexception-mypkg-myobje) worked for me